# Create fipImage* from unsigned char*(freeimage)?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeimage

```
unsigned char * image_data;
int bytes; // size

format:
RGBA , UNSIGNED_BYTE.
(opengl-glGetTexImage()):
```

How can i create  fipImage* from this data?

C++.

---

```
unsigned char * image_data;
int w = 1000;
int h = 1000;
```

this function write to image_data

```
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 , GL_RGBA , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , image_data);
```

i want to create fipImage from image_data

```
fipImage image;
something like this
image.load(image_data ,w , h);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking about here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a FreeImage object from your raw pixels the following way:

```
FIBITMAP* Bitmap = FreeImage_Allocate( Width, Height, BitsPP, 0, 0, 0 );

memcpy( FreeImage_GetBits( Bitmap ), image_data, Width * Height * ( BitsPP / 8 ) );
```